# RaspberryPi virtual MIDI cable

Tags: raspberry-pi, port, raspbian, midi

I need to connect two MIDI programs with a virtual MIDI cable (or port) on Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian, exactly like loopMIDI does on Windows. (https://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html)

I know there has to be a way to create a virtual port using alsa or another common system on the PI, I just haven't been able to find that specific information/instruction.

Comment: Does Raspbian include the `snd-seq-dummy` module and the `aconnect` tool?

Comment: It does include `aconnect`, but not the other.

Comment: Does it have any `snd-seq*` module, or `/dev/snd/seq`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jack](http://jackaudio.org/) for this. After installation, start Jack in a terminal with:

```
jack_control start
```

A Python example (requires [JACKClient](https://pypi.org/project/JACK-Client/)):

```
import jack

midiInBuffer = []
midiOutBuffer = []

client = jack.Client('jack')

midi_in = client.midi_inports.register('midi_in)
midi_out = client.midi_outports.register('midi_out')

@client.set_process_callback

def process(frames):

  midi_out.clear_buffer()
  if (len(midiOutBuffer)):
    for msg in midiOutBuffer:
      midi_out.write_midi_event(0, msg)
      print('MIDI sent = ', msg)
  midiOutBuffer.clear()

  for offset, data in midi_in.incoming_midi_events():
    msg = struct.unpack('3B', data)
    midiInBuffer.append(msg)
    print('MIDI rcvd = ', msg)

client.activate()

print(client.midi_inports)
print(client.midi_outports)

# forward all incoming messages from midi_in to midi_out
while True:
  for msg in midiInBuffer
    midiOutBuffer.append(msg)
    print('MIDI fwd = ', msg)
  midiInBuffer.clear()
```

Now use the jack:midi_out port to send the MIDI messages from one MIDI program to another and read these MIDI messages in the other MIDI program from the jack:midi_in port.